# Initializing manually rendered choice field on validation error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've got a choice field that I'm manually rendering in my template.

**template.html**

```
                   <select name="pricing" id="id_pricing">
                        <option value> Make a selection </option>

                         {% for value, object in form.pricing.field.choices %}

                            <option 

                                    value="{{value}}"                                            
                                    {% if form.pricing.initial == value %}
                                       selected
                                    {% endif %}

                            >

                                {{object}}

                            </option>

                            {% endfor %}

                        </select>
```

This works 100% with one exception. If there is a validation error that gets thrown on another field due to checks that I have in def clean(), on the reload of the page, the value that populates the choice field isn't the one that the user just selected prior to submitting the form. It's 'Make a selection'.

Do you know how I can ensure that the value that populates the choice field on reload of page due to validation error is the one that the user selected?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: I can. It involves getting the users selection, sending back to django via ajax to create session variables, detecting presence of errors on load and initializing the choice fields based on prior selection. I can do it, but dont want to if there is a quick fix.